# plm package: 'system is exactly singular' error in random-effects model (Swamy-Arora estimation)

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, random-effects

I have stumbled upon quite a few questions with a similar issue, but cannot find any with an answer. My issue is with the data copied at the end of this post, which reproduces a dataset that I am trying to get through a random-effects model, using the `plm` package.

The error looks like this:

```r
# data provided at end of post

library(plm)
plm(y ~ x + factor(year), index = "panel", model = "random", data = df)

# Error in solve.default(crossprod(ZBeta)) : 
#  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[15,15] = 0
```

The issue is with the `factor(year)` part. What I do not understand is that the same model and data works perfectly in Stata:

```
xtreg y x i.year, re sa
// output omitted
```

(The `sa` option above selects the same Swamy-Arora estimation technique that is used by default by `plm`. Thanks to Nir Graham for his answer, which led me to observing this.)

Removing years for which I have only one observation in this (very unbalanced) panel does not help. Any assistance would be very much appreciated!

```r
> dput(df)
structure(list(y = c(0.32, 0.51, 0.26, 0.99, 0.59, 0.43, 0.6, 
0.86, 1, 0.97, 0.89, 0.63, 0.55, 0.58, 0.26, 0.69, 0.87, 0.17, 
0.09, 0, 0.87, 0.39, 0.36, 0.73, 0.13, 0.61, 0.36, 0.64, 0.72, 
0.95, 0.8, 0.96, 0.32, 0.91, 0.77, 0.14, 0.37, 0.57, 0.81, 0.98, 
0.5, 0.23, 0.8, 0.04, 0.84, 0.12, 0.56, 0.22, 0.49, 0.65, 0.59, 
0.98, 0.71, 0.58, 0.75, 0.77, 0.49, 0.72, 0.29, 0.2, 0.67, 0.06, 
0.36, 0.44, 0.65, 0.29, 0.85, 0.75, 0.2, 0.44, 0.7, 0.54, 0.19, 
0.47, 0.83, 0.47, 0.23, 0.43, 0.6, 0.48, 0.63, 0.95, 1, 0.46, 
0.28, 0.88, 0.82, 0.71, 0.57, 0.25, 0.78, 0.07, 0.45, 0.7, 0.08, 
0.2, 0.5, 0.13, 0.56, 0.12, 0.08, 0.29, 0.89, 0.37, 0.96, 0.83, 
0.81, 0.02, 0.96, 0.83, 0.51, 0.04, 0.04, 0.06, 0.44, 0.61, 0.99, 
0.83, 0.31, 0.82, 0.12, 0.18, 0.89, 0.23, 0.46, 0.73, 0.76, 0.49, 
0.32, 0.87, 0.11, 0.01, 0.96, 0.86, 0.91, 0.68, 0.8, 0.63, 0.94, 
1, 0.59, 0.5, 0.01, 0.48, 0.86, 0.92, 0.07, 0.15, 0.07, 0.33, 
0.6, 0.52, 0.12, 0.59, 0.56, 0.56, 0.55, 0.18, 0.11, 0.16, 0.27, 
0.06, 0.62, 0.34, 0.69, 0.87, 0.32, 0.31, 0.1, 0.44, 0.99, 0.96, 
0.72, 0.19, 0.81), x = c(0.25, 0.41, 0.55, 0.77, 0.95, 0.2, 0.36, 
0.58, 0.27, 0.56, 0.53, 0.88, 0.55, 0.43, 0.19, 0.54, 0.2, 0.37, 
0.18, 0.09, 0.26, 0.15, 0.75, 0.08, 0.55, 0.06, 0.23, 0.9, 0.12, 
0.51, 0.58, 0.54, 0.88, 0.24, 0.9, 0.85, 0.32, 0.43, 0.66, 0.12, 
0.09, 0.75, 0.5, 0.11, 0.07, 0.04, 0.6, 0.96, 0.39, 0.61, 0.23, 
0.28, 0.45, 0.55, 0.52, 0.99, 0.96, 0.64, 0.31, 0.47, 0.01, 0.56, 
0.7, 0.88, 0.13, 0.87, 0.2, 0.62, 0.42, 0.85, 0.5, 0.22, 0.52, 
0.15, 0.31, 0.23, 0.09, 0.76, 0.56, 0.29, 0.42, 0.87, 0.75, 0.78, 
0.67, 0.94, 0.69, 0.74, 0.07, 0.22, 0.47, 0.52, 0.85, 0.28, 0.47, 
0.39, 0.34, 0.94, 0.14, 0.5, 0.16, 0.2, 0.22, 0.71, 0.66, 0.68, 
0.54, 0.24, 0.04, 0.1, 0.44, 0.54, 0.23, 0.53, 0.24, 0.14, 0.99, 
0.18, 0.93, 0.99, 0.49, 0.39, 0.78, 0.41, 0.31, 0.11, 0.75, 0.59, 
0.85, 0.31, 0.8, 0.21, 0.67, 0.31, 0.21, 0.88, 0.84, 0.32, 0.36, 
0.89, 0.4, 0.82, 0.54, 0.18, 0.4, 0.71, 0.28, 0.83, 0.78, 0.07, 
0.93, 0.47, 0.44, 0.49, 0.71, 0.69, 0, 0.47, 0.72, 0.06, 0.13, 
0.65, 0.12, 0.26, 0.67, 0.8, 0.4, 0.82, 0.22, 0.16, 0.32, 0.01, 
0.53, 0.26, 0.99), panel = c("p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", 
"p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p3", "p3", 
"p3", "p3", "p4", "p4", "p4", "p4", "p5", "p5", "p5", "p5", "p6", 
"p6", "p6", "p6", "p6", "p6", "p6", "p6", "p6", "p7", "p7", "p7", 
"p7", "p7", "p7", "p7", "p7", "p7", "p8", "p8", "p8", "p8", "p8", 
"p8", "p8", "p8", "p9", "p9", "p9", "p9", "p10", "p10", "p10", 
"p10", "p10", "p10", "p11", "p11", "p11", "p11", "p11", "p11", 
"p11", "p11", "p11", "p12", "p12", "p12", "p12", "p12", "p12", 
"p12", "p12", "p12", "p13", "p13", "p13", "p13", "p13", "p13", 
"p13", "p13", "p13", "p14", "p14", "p14", "p15", "p15", "p15", 
"p15", "p16", "p16", "p16", "p16", "p16", "p16", "p16", "p16", 
"p16", "p17", "p17", "p17", "p17", "p17", "p17", "p17", "p17", 
"p17", "p18", "p18", "p18", "p18", "p19", "p19", "p19", "p19", 
"p19", "p19", "p19", "p19", "p19", "p20", "p20", "p20", "p20", 
"p21", "p21", "p21", "p21", "p22", "p22", "p22", "p22", "p22", 
"p22", "p22", "p22", "p22", "p23", "p23", "p23", "p23", "p24", 
"p24", "p24", "p24", "p24", "p24", "p24", "p24", "p25", "p25", 
"p25", "p25", "p26", "p26", "p26", "p26", "p27", "p27", "p27", 
"p27", "p28", "p28", "p28", "p28", "p28", "p28"), year = c(8, 
9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 11, 12, 14, 
15, 10, 12, 14, 15, 10, 12, 14, 15, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 
15, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 
10, 12, 14, 15, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 
14, 15, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 
14, 15, 13, 14, 15, 10, 12, 14, 15, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 
15, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 10, 12, 14, 15, 1, 3, 5, 6, 
9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 10, 12, 14, 15, 10, 12, 14, 15, 1, 3, 5, 6, 
9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 10, 12, 14, 15, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 
11, 12, 14, 15, 10, 12, 14, 15, 10, 12, 14, 15, 7, 9, 10, 12, 
14, 15)), row.names = c(NA, -175L), class = "data.frame")
```

P.S. [Cross-posted](https://github.com/ycroissant/plm/issues/32) to the issues of the package.

Answer (score 0):

plm has a few algorithms ; perhaps random.method = "nerlove" gets you closer to what you want

Comment: Thank you. That's a very good lead, since changing `random.method` to `"nerlove"` (or `"ameyima"`, which seems to be what Stata uses by default) does allow the model to estimate properly. However, the default `random.method` for `plm` is `"swar"`, which has an equivalent in Stata (`xtreg y x, re sa`), and that equivalent estimates fine in Stata, but not in `plm` (as shown in my question), so the issue does remain. Thanks again, anyway!

Comment: Note that `, re sa` is not fully equivalent to what `plm`'s `swar` does. plm does what is in the literature while Stata made a small adjustment yet still calling it Swamy-Arora, see this (and linked literature in there): https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421413/94889. It is also noted in plm's vignette (in a footnote as far as I remember).

Comment: That is correct. I realised so earlier by reading the Cottrell 2017 paper, which is cited by `plm` vignette B: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/B_plmFunction.html -- However, the error I'm getting is really hard to relate to that (very slight) difference.